# Possible to style Zurb Foundation Joyride like this?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

Just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to style Foundation's Joyride tooltips to look something like [this](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/14521/screenshots/1216346/demo_tour_2_dribbble_5.png)?

Specifically the little progress indicator and the placement of the button.

or even if anyone could point me towards some sort of resource in how to set something like this up?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the definition of possible :)

Comment: Are you asking if someone has already done this?  Go ask in the SO chat rooms rather than a posted question so you don't get down-voted into oblivion or ignored.